# Europa Universalis IV Kinslayer Achievement Question

Tags: achievements, europa-universalis-iv

Usually a dynasty question like this would involve PU. But for once it doesn't.

I am playing a Ryzan that has manage to grow up to about 500ish total development (Mostly in Crimea/Ruthenia area). I plan to enlist Russia (with one of the last surviving Rurikovich beside your truly to expand into baltic/danzig area.

I was hoping that Russia through one or various wars they had along me would cause a non-Rurikovich to come to term. They somehow manage to survive being shred to low manpower AND westernization at the same time...

Good news although I get 10% discount for tech!

Bad news I am trying to figure out a way to cause a non-native dynasty to come to term. Couldn't really comes up with one so.

I am aware that the simplest way is to conquest their land. But AI Russia being "annoying AI" decide it was a good idea to have Quantity... They can easily field 120ish units. While I am barely at 60. So ideally I would like to keep them around as a punch bag.

**Question:** Put simply. What is the best way to get a foreign heir on another country? Does turn revolutionary cause the dynasty for Russia to change right?

I plan to use a vassal to grow in Caucasian due to "50% extra cost to coring". If their dynasty count against you then I could just diplo-annex them not a big deal.

**Question:** Do vassal's family count against you?